# Table of integrals for complex exponentials involving delta functions

Tags: integration, complex-integration, dirac-delta

I am interested in finding a list of integrals of the form:

$$ \int a^n e^{iax} da$$

For $n = 0$, I found it to be $\delta(x)$.

For $n = -1$, I found it to be sgn$(x)$.

For $n = -2$, I found it to be $\lvert x \rvert $.

But what is the value for $n = 1$? And more generally, is there a table of integrals evaluating the above for any integer $n$? These appear to be widely used integrals yet I was unable to find their exact expressions documented in tables.

Comment: Do you want an answer in the sense of distributions? In the ordinary sense, the Fourier transform does not exist for the functions above, as they do not decay quickly enough.

Comment: To clarify, for the $n=1$ case, the Fourier transform does not exist? Distributions would be helpful and any references for the integrals when $n \geq 0$ and/or $n < 0$ would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the classical sense, the integrals do not exist for any $n$, at the value $x=0$. For $n\geq 0$, this is because $a^n$ does not decay at infinity. For $n<0$, the singularity at $0$ is too poor. If we instead consider the tempered distributions associated with $a^n$, that is the functional $T_{a^n}\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ given by $T_{a^n} (\phi) = \int_\mathbb{R} a^n \phi\, da$ against test functions $\phi \in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, then the Fourier transforms exist as distributions. The Fourier transform (both the normal one and the one on distributions) satisfies $\mathcal{F}(\frac{df}{da})=ix\mathcal{F}(f)$. For $n>0$, this gives us $\mathcal{F}(T_{a^n}) = \frac{1}{i^n}\delta^{(n)}$, where $\delta^{(n)}$ is the nth distributional derivative of $\delta$. For negative powers, if $n>0$, $\mathcal{F}(T_{a^{-n}})$ is the distribution associated with $\frac{(ix)^n}{|x|}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you happen to have any references that further discuss computing these integrals in detail and/or provide explicit formulas for particular $\phi$ (e.g. constant, polynomial)?

Comment: And to clarify for the case of $n = 1$ above, this would correspond to $\phi = 1$. Yet the first distributional derivative of $\delta$ would be $\delta^{(1)} = -\phi'(0) = 0$. Therefore, to confirm, is the integral zero for $\phi = 1$ and $n = 1$?